# Eigenvalues of matrix product $AB$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two matrices $A,B$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix. Suppose I know the eigenvalues of $B$. Is there a way to infer the eigenvalues of $AB$, exploiting the fact that $A$ is diagonal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.  For example, $B_1 = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d}$ and $B_2 = \pmatrix{d & b\cr c & a\cr}$ have the same eigenvalues, but if $A = \pmatrix{e & 0 \cr 0 & f\cr}$ with $f \ne e$ and $a \ne d$, $AB_1$ and $A B_2$ will have different eigenvalues (because their traces will be  different).

Comment: Thanks. Please see another version of the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320103/10063, where $B$ is restricted to satisfy additional properties.